# Cannot execute a method from another class using delegate pattern (swift)

Tags: swift, delegates

I am new in Swift. I'm trying to understand how the delegate pattern works. Below is some code that I have tried to implement. The goal is to execute one method (printing()) from another class. I cannot achieve the expected behaviour for some reasons.

The first class:

```
protocol  ViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func printing()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.printing()
    } 
}
```

The second class:

```
class Class: UIViewController,ViewControllerDelegate {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = ViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
    }

    func printing () {
        print("PRINT")
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating you presenting your VCs? From code or using a storyboard?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I use storyboard (segue).

Comment: Is `delegate?.printing()` even called? If yes, could you check the value of `delegate?`. I'm wondering if because `let vc = ViewController()` is a local variable, it might be released too soon. If that's the case, make `vc` a property of your `Class` instance. Else, it's because `button(_sender:)` isn't called, and that's another issue. Because when you do `ViewController()` you are creating a new instance, not the on you pushed/presented/see with your segue.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I used Class(UIViewController) because it is more clear for me in terms of implementing the delegate pattern. My original goal was to implement a method from another class that is UIView: 


class Class: UIView, ViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func printing () {
        print("PRINT")
    }
}

Comment: @Larme I checked the value of  delegate? .  Delegate.ViewControllerDelegate? nil

Comment: It's "it is more clear for me in terms of implementing the delegate pattern", yes and no. It's simpler indeed, but in reality, as said, the ViewController that you are seing is not `vc`. You create a whole new instance. Just like when you do `let myVar1 = Something(); let myVar2 = Something()`, it doesn't mean that's the one you see on screen.

Comment: @Larme Thank you so much! ```override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)``` works for this case. Could you please give me a hint about what should be done in case of   ```class Class: UIView``` ? If I want to call a function from another class without presenting anything. Maybe I should use a singleton pattern.